# add service to a running supervisord in a running container

Tags: docker, supervisord

I understood that in order to manage multiple services inside a container I need to use supervisord.

my question is how to add a service after container is already running?

I have a container that the service is created inside it after it is already running so I need to add it later on.

currently I am trying to do user "service sec restart" ( sec is my service ) and it is failing since docker won't allow it

many thanks

Comment: Do you know the service definition before hand? Then you can delay the start of the same

Comment: what do you mean by service definition? I know the service name and the invocation command even though it does not exist yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the service name and command you can create your conf like below

```
[program:myapp]
command=echo "this is my command"
autostart=false
```

This will make sure that command doesn't start automatically when Supervisor/container starts. When you are ready in your container to start the command then you can use below inside the container

```
supervisorctl start myapp
```

Comment: sounds great , I will test it now